# Can I read the rest of the line after a positive value of IOSTAT?

Tags: csv, file-io, fortran

I have a file with 13 columns and 41 lines consisting of the coefficients for the [Joback Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joback_method) for 41 different groups. Some of the values are non-existing, though, and the table lists them as "X". I saved the table as a .csv and in my code read the file to an array. An excerpt of two lines from the .csv (the second one contains non-exisiting coefficients) looks like this:

```
48.84,11.74,0.0169,0.0074,9.0,123.34,163.16,453.0,1124.0,-31.1,0.227,-0.00032,0.000000146
X,74.6,0.0255,-0.0099,X,23.61,X,797.0,X,X,X,X,X
```

What I've tried doing was to read and define an array to hold each IOSTAT value so I can know if an "X" was read (that is, IOSTAT would be positive):

```
DO I = 1, 41
        (READ(25,*,IOSTAT=ReadStatus(I,J)) JobackCoeff, J = 1, 13)
END DO
```

The problem, I've found, is that if the first value of the line to be read is "X", producing a positive value of ReadStatus, then the rest of the values of those line are not read correctly.

My intent was to use the ReadStatus array to produce an error message if JobackCoeff(I,J) caused a read error, therefore pinpointing the "X"s.

Can I force the program to keep reading a line after there is a reading error? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as an error occurs during the input execution then processing of the input list terminates.  Further, all variables specified in the input list become undefined.  The short answer to your first question is: no, there is no way to keep reading a line after a reading error.

We come, then, to the usual answer when more complicated input processing is required: read the line into a character variable and process that.  I won't write complete code for you (mostly because it isn't clear exactly what is required), but when you have a character variable you may find the `index` intrinsic useful.  With this you can locate `X`s (with repeated calls on substrings to find all of them on a line).

Alternatively, if you provide an explicit format (rather than relying on list-directed (`fmt=*`) input) you may be able to do something with non-advancing input (`advance='no'` in the `read` statement).  However, as soon as an error condition comes about then the position of the file becomes indeterminate: you'll also have to handle this.  It's probably much simpler to process the line-as-a-character-variable.

An outline of the concept (without declarations, robustness) is given below.

```
read(iunit, '(A)') line
idx = 1    
do i=1, 13
  read(line(idx:), *, iostat=iostat) x(i)
  if (iostat.gt.0) then
    print '("Column ",I0," has an X")', i
    x(i) = -HUGE(0.)  ! Recall x(i) was left undefined
  end if
  idx = idx + INDEX(line(idx:), ',')
end do
```

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, you are suggesting I read all lines as characters and then parse them?

Comment: Yes.  If you want to do anything other than detect whether an error occurs you'll need to do some extra handling.  This, fortunately, isn't too tricky, as my example hopefully shows.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, long used by many many Fortran programmers, and programmers in other languages, would be to use an editor of some sort (I like `sed`) and modify the file by changing all the `X`s to `NAN`s.  Your compiler has to provide support for `IEEE NaN`s for this to work (most of the current crop in widespread use do) and they will correctly interpret `NAN` in the input file to a real number with value `NaN`.

This approach has the benefit, compared with the already accepted (and perfectly good) answer, of not requiring clever programming in Fortran to parse input lines containing mixed entries.  Use an editor for string processing, use Fortran for reading numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it will sure come in handy in the future. For this case, however, I actually use the fact that there was a reading error in my subroutine to inform the user that a value is unavailable. Could I do something similar by checking if the read value is NaN? Would that be even possible, seeing that the variables are real?

Comment: There's a Fortran intrinsic function `ieee_is_nan` for testing the nan-ness of a value.

Comment: I see. Guess that would be a simpler solution, then. Thank you